# Transferring Windows 10 to new SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, operating-systems, windows-easy-transfer

I have a notebook with Windows 10 installed on an 128GB SSD and I want to just transfer it to a new SSD I have added (512GB). Both SSDs have data on them. Assuming there is sufficient space, what is the easiest method to transfer my current windows 10 installation to the new SSD ?

Comment: The easiest way is to clone the SSD.

Comment: This is a good question...downvoters should clarify if this a duplicate; if this isn't a duplicate I can't see any reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will first need to empty the new SSD; so temporarily copy the data elsewhere.
- Then, create a bootable USB stick with [EasyUS TODO](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/backup-bootableCD.htm) (free tool)
- Initialize the new SSD (make sure there is a partition on it), otherwise EasyUS doesn't detect the drive.
- Connect the drives

  - If you have room for two internal SSD's, cloning should not be an issue, just make sure to select the correct source/target drive. Just put both SSD's into your system.
  - If you only have room for one drive, remove the SSD containing your OS, and insert the new SSD. Attach the OS SSD through USB 3 using a sata to usb 3 cable or SATA docking station. (EasyUS doesn't work in the other direction)
- Insert the bootable USB stick in the "first" USB port (might need trial and error to figuer out which port this is). Change your bios settings to boot from USB. If the EasyUS tool does not load, your USB drive is possibly connected to the wrong USB port.
- When EasyUS boots, just use the wizard to clone from the OS SSD to the new SSD.

I've used this method 20+ times. Aside from the mess with finding the "first" USB port, it works smoothly. Also, that issue might be brand-specific (i used DELL's).

Good luck!

And, make sure you have backups, obviously.

Comment: I cannot connect drives externally through USB because they are M2s and I have no adapter for that, but both can work in the same time (got 2 slots). I've marked the answer as correct since this solution is universally valid.